# Laravel: Geocoder Error Call to a member function on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

#### General Information

I'm using [this](https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel) package

GeocoderLaravel Version: 4.0.0

Laravel Version: 5.6

PHP Version:  7.2.4

Operating System and Version:  Windows 10

#### Issue Description

`FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function getStreetNumber() on null`

This happens maybe 1/10 times. Even when I use the same coordinates. Rest of the time it works fine. If I get the error and just refresh/resubmit the form it will work. So not sure how to solve this issue.

My one guess is that it is exicuting `Location::create()` before an object is returned to `$geo`, but I don't know what could be done to fix that. Any help would be much appreciated

Here is my controller:

```
    $lat = request('lat');
    $lng = request('lng');
    $geo = Geocoder::reverse($lat, $lng)->get()->first();

    $location = Location::create([
        'lat'           => $lat,
        'lng'           => $lng,
        'user_id'       => Auth::user()->id,
        'streetNumber'  => $geo->getStreetNumber(),
        'streetName'    => $geo->getStreetName(),
        'cityDistrict'  => $geo->getSubLocality(),
        'city'          => $geo->getLocality(),
        'zipcode'       => $geo->getPostalCode(),
        'country'       => $geo->getCountry(),
        'timezone'      => $geo->getTimezone()
    ]);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package, but `$geo` will be null if `Geocoder::get()` returns an empty collection. I assume it would return an empty collection if the coordinates couldn't be found.

Comment: Good point. It may be a problem with my server since it finds the coordinates when I resubmit. Something is not communicating properly.